# Theme not displaying correctly (logo, terminal) 16.04

Tags: unity, compiz, themes

After a massive upgrade through Software Updater, some dependecies issues popped out, which I was able to resolve by running sudo aptitude.

However, now I get the following problems. The theme Numix, Paper, etc. are not displayed correctly, i.e. the menues are white, or the terminal.

Plus, when I boot Ubuntu, the usual graphics logo is now this:

[image]

And here's the terminal.

[image]

What can I do to reset that?
I've tried reseting unity and compiz, changing themes through UNity Tweak tool, nothing works.

Comment: You upgraded with PPAs turned on?

Comment: I didn't upgrade the distribution, only a regular software update in 16.04.01. LTS.

Comment: Even if you upgrade in release, these PPAs can cause problem. you should disable PPAs before upgrade. nevertheless, I think you should try remove the plymouth theme from numix PPA. and about the white menus, those are from Paper theme. This theme' menu is white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem.
First I ran:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

And selected

```
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth        100       manual mode
```

And it worked fine.

To solve the theme inconsistencies, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge numix*
```

Removing both the gtk-theme and the icon-theme, restarted, re-added the PPA of Numix, and installed the theme, went to Unity Tweak Tool, selected Numix and it was fine.